# Keep getting error code - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, int

Im trying to make a program that always produces the sum of two three-digit numbers, derived from the difference of two other three-digit numbers, as 1089, provided that the originally chosen number’s first and third digits differ by two or more. I will clarify that i am very new to this and only know the very basics. This is what i have so far.

```
num1 = input("Choose a three digit number whose first and third digits vary by at least two numbers.")

num2 = num1[2] + num1[1] + num1[0]

if int(num1) < int(num2):

    difference = int(num2) - (num1)
else:

    difference = int(num1) - (num2)

newNum1 = str(difference)

newNum2 = newNum1[2] + newNum1[1] + newNum1[0]

ten89 = int(newNum1) + int(newNum2)

print ("If you chose your three-digit number correctly your should have gotten 1089 and you got," ,ten89)
```

I keep getting the error code -

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str' - for the line - difference = int(num2) - (num1).

I tried changing the int in that line to str, as well as others. If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add `int` here: `difference = int(num2) - (num1)` and here: `difference = int(num1) - (num2)`.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because `num1` is a string.

Everything returned by `input` is a string. You need to convert to an `int` to be able to use mathematical operations.

```
 >>> num1 = input("Choose a three digit number whose first and third digits vary by at least two numbers.")
 >>> ..... 123
 >>> print(type(num1))
 >>> <class 'str'>
```